# How to make cmake identify correct version in centos 6 terminal?

Tags: cmake, centos6, emscripten

After a very long and lengthy process of trying to get Emscripten going. I'm stuck trying to build fastcomp.

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
>   -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;JSBackend" -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF -DCLANG_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF

It gives this error:

> CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake:12 (message): 
>   Host GCC version must be at least 4.8!

I've installed devtools 2 and actiavted the toolset.

`gcc --version` reads as using gcc 4.8.2, but it just won't go.

I've also tried:

```
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc  
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++  
export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cpp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At the beginning of `cmake ...` output, CMake shows which exact compiler it uses. Add this output into your question post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem until I recompiled a recent version of cmake with the newer version of gcc already "activated".

Then, with the CC, CXX and CPP environment variables also set to the appropriate paths, cmake then stopped giving that "Host GCC version must be at least 4.8!" error.